# Django search field with ajax that shows result dropdown with hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jquery-select2

I have a Django app and in this app I want to implement a search field. When a user starts typing the name of a student, I want to return all student names that match via Ajax through a dropdown search result.

However, I want the results to be hyperlinks, so when a user sees the correct entry and clicks on it, he will be redirected to the detail page of the student.

I managed to follow this tutorial: http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/

but it inserts the results just in the webpage and moves all the content down. Instead, I would like to display it in a dropdown-like field like in this image:
[image]

which is the example from select2 which was recommended to me. However, I do not want a select field. Instead, the user should on click be redirected to whatever link is embedded in the search result (in this case e.g. the github page) but I was not able to achieve that yet.

Is this something I can get select2 to do for me? Is this something I can achieve with bootstrap?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [templateResult](https://select2.github.io/options.html#can-i-change-how-the-placeholder-looks) to change results:

```js
var results = [
  {img: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico', text: 'qwerty', url: '#'},
  {img: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico', text: 'zxcvbn', url: '#'},
  {img: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico', text: 'asdfgh', url: '#'},
];

$("[name='results']").select2({
        placeholder: "Enter search query",
        templateResult: function(result) {
            return $(
              '<a href="' + result.url + '"><img class="search-result-img" src="' + result.img + '">' + result.text + '</a>'
            );
        },
        data: results
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="text" name="results" />
```